# How can I set the innerText of two html nodes where one is a child?

Tags: javascript, innertext

In javaScript, can someone please help me to set the textContent of x amount of html nodes, where the html nodes can be child html nodes?

Here is the javaScript function that I have:

```
function setTextContent(className, data)
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
        elements[i].textContent = data;
    }
}
```

Here is the html that I have:

```
<div class="test"><div class="test2"></div></div>
```

Here are the two function calls:

```
setTextContent('test', "testString1");
setTextContent('test2', "testString2");
```

The data that I get displayed is just:

```
testString1
```

How can i get the following displayed:

```
testString1
testString2
```

I would like to please do this without jQuery and would like this code to be able to used on any element structure, where html nodes can have many other html nodes with html attributes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, looks like you want to insert the text at the beginning of the parent element so

```js
function setTextContent(className, data) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className),
    el;
  for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    el = elements[i];
    if (!el.firstChild) { //if there are no contents within the element insert a text node
      el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
    } else if (el.firstChild.nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE) { //if the first child is not a text node then insert one
      el.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(''), el.firstChild);
    }
    el.firstChild.textContent = data;
  }
}

setTextContent('test', "testString1");
setTextContent('test2', "testString2");
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will the code you provided work in all html nodes, irrelevant or the html node structure? I do not want to break any existing data that is displayed in any html nodes that I set the textContent for.

Comment: it should... because if the first child node is not a text node then it will create a new one

Comment: Also, how can the code be modified to set the innerHtml and the value of x amount of html nodes? I am trying to use replacements for jQuery common actions, without using jQuery.

Comment: If the intention is to emulate *textContent*, then any text nodes that are children of the parent should be removed first, up to the first element node, and replaced with a new text node.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setTextContent(className, data) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    var node=document.createTextNode(data);
    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
        elements[i].insertBefore(node, elements[i].childNodes[0]);
    }
}
setTextContent('test', "testString1");
setTextContent('test2', "testString2");
```

```html
  <div class="test">
      <div class="test2"></div>
  </div>
```

create text node and insert it before childNode[0]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,

```
function setTextContent(className, data) {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
        for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
            elements[i].innerHTML = data + elements[i].innerHTML; //Append the data with children nodes.
        }
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xd4012jc/)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to replace the first text node or nodes within an element. If there are no leading text nodes, insert some. The following should do the job:

```js
function insertText(element, text) {
  while (element.firstChild && element.firstChild.nodeType != 1) {
    element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
  }
  element.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(text), element.firstChild);
}
```

```html
<div id="d0">text at the begining<span> some in a span </span>and more<div>
<button onclick="insertText(document.getElementById('d0'), 'new text 0')">Insert 0</button>
<div id="d1">only text, nothing else<div>
<button onclick="insertText(document.getElementById('d1'), 'new text 1')">Insert 1</button>
<div>empty element following <span id="s0"></span><div>
<button onclick="insertText(document.getElementById('s0'), 'new text 2')">Insert 2</button>
```